# Type Undefined is not assignable to type [Film]

Tags: json, angular, http, observable

I am learning how to make http request in angular using service and here is my code:

```
export class ApiCallService {
    // DECLARATIONS:
    tmdb_api_key = '*******'; // personal api key to access the TMDB API
    posterBaseAddress = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300'; // base 
    address of the TMDB poster link, to add film specific path
   // SEARCH PARAMETERS
   requestPages: number; // get the number of pages for the request so is possible to load all the films (request is 1 page at time)
    pageToLoad = 1; // number of page to load, start with 1
    baseLanguage = 'en-US'; // return film in english, search can be done in local language but return english titles
    foundFilms: [Film] = [];

constructor(private http: Http) {}
// TODO: GET method to search for film

getFilmsByTitle(filmTitle: string, page: number) {
    // if the search has only 1 page will be 1 otherwise will load the films on the respective page
    this.pageToLoad = page;
    return this.http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?' +
    'api_key=*******$' +
    '&language=' + this.baseLanguage +
    '&query=' + filmTitle +
    '&page=' + this.pageToLoad +
    '&include_adult=false')
        .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                const films = response.json();
                for (const film of films['results']) {
                    const singleFilm = new Film(film.title, film.overview, film.release_date, film.poster_path, film.genre_ids);
                    this.foundFilms.push(singleFilm);
                }
                this.requestPages = films.total_pages;
                return this.foundFilms;
            }
        );
}
}


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private apiCallService: ApiCallService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.apiCallService.getFilmsByTitle('Harry', 1).subscribe(
  (films: [any]) => {
    console.log(films);
  }
);
  }
}
```

When I launch the app I get this error, **ERROR in src/app/services/apicall.service.ts(15,5): error TS2322: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type '[Film]'.
  Property '0' is missing in type 'undefined[]'.**

And in the console I have this error: **Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

I don't understand why, i tried several was to declare the foundFilms array but I cannot make it work.

I hope someone can help

Thanks
Alessandro

Comment: Try to declare this way `foundFilms: Film[] = [];`. Try also to use the HttpClient instead of Http. (https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: yes, I read that now is better to use HttpClient, but still I don't get the error, also if the app works fine

Comment: Can you maybe post an updated version of your code?

Comment: Done, code updated and I have added the app.component where I subscribe to the Observable

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize your array when you declare it.

`foundFilms: Film[] = [];`

Comment: I tried it, the app works but the error in the angular console after ng serve remain...  is it maybe due to the fact that the function return an observable?

Comment: Did you update your type annotation to Film[] instead of [Film]?

Comment: If I do that, the error disappear but the app crash due to the second error i posted above: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Nothing changes :(

Comment: Is not an array of arerays, but an array of objects

Comment: You're right, I noticed that after posting that comment sorry.

Comment: "for (const film of films['results'])" here you should use "for(let film of films['results']);" and also change the "const singleFilm"  to "let singleFilm "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165986/discussion-between-narm-and-aspnet82).